# Being a reviewer for a top Computer Science conference means, as a general rule, to have the possibility of attending for free?

Tags: peer-review, conference, computer-science

Just wondering if, as a general rule, there is any "benefit" (e.g. free attendance) associated to being a PC member in Computer Science conferences

Comment: Why don’t you just ask the conference organisers? Surely that’s better than some strangers guessing on the internet.

Comment: yes sure, I was just wondering what is the "general rule", if any

Comment: This question strongly depends on the specifics of the conference in consideration.

Comment: If you are a student, you can probably get a discounted attendance. You can also serve as a volunteer at some conferences and likely not need to pay.

Comment: @deltasun perhaps edit your question to reflect that then - ‘is there a general rule about whether it’s possible to get free entry … etc’ rather than a specific case

Comment: The benefit is that it demonstrates, in some small way, to potential hiring committees that your peers take you seriously as a scientist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While any conference in CS can set its own rules and can have its own way of financing, the vast majority of good conferences barely breaks even and is financed exclusively from attendance fees. Usually, you work hard to make the conference affordable. So, PC members can count their service as service to the community but do not get free attendance.

In general, all PC members are expected to review. Sometimes only PC members review, sometimes PC members are responsible that the papers assigned to them are reviewed by either themselves or by others. PC members get to vote on the final selection. But you cannot equate PC members with reviewers.